# Windows Domain Controller "Security Folder" Permissions

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, domain-controller, file-permissions

anybody know if on %WindowsPath%\security the "Authenticated Users" and "Server Operators" must have "Traverse Folder" permissions on a Domain Controller (Windows 2003).

An external audit over my company observed that I not sure if they are right.

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an unusual recommendation.  The only time I have seen that permission removed is to prevent executing files, similar to noexec.